# How to check in Razor view if ApplicationUser.Roles contains certain role?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have 3 roles in my webapp: `Admin`,`Moderator`,`User`.

I have a user `@model WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationUser` I want to check inside Razor view if `user.Roles` contains role `Moderator`. How to do so? I tried `@if(@Model.Roles.Contains(DON'T_KNOW_WHAT_TO_WRITE_HERE){}`.

**NOTE:** I am not asking how to check if currently authorized user is in certain role.

Comment: What is `Model.Roles`?

Comment: @AntP `Model.Roles` is property of `ApplicationUser` it was introtuced in standard template in ASP.NET MVC 5(in older versions Authorization was done differently). This property was generated by Visual Studio while creating a new project with Individual Accounts.

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is create an extension method on `IPrincipal` that operates the same way as `User.IsInRole(...)`

```
public static bool IsInAppRole(this IPrincipal user, string role)
{
    using(var db = new MyEntities())
    {
        var dbUser = db.Users.Find(user.Identity.GetUserId());
        return dbUser.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleName == role)
    }
}
```

Import extensions into a view

```
@using MyApplication.Web.Extensions
```

Use like you would `IsInRole()`

```
@if(User.IsInAppRole("Admin"))
{
}
```

Though, not sure why you'd do this as the user's roles can be put into their `Identity` object.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way that I could find is to use:

```
@Model.Roles.SingleOrDefault().RoleId
```

This, of course, requires you to work with the ID rather than the name in your comparison. Without creating a new ViewModel, I have not found a good way to get direct access to the name.

EDIT: If multiple roles are assigned, you should be able to do something like this:

```
@{
    var isMod = false;
}
foreach (var r in Model.Roles)
{
    if(r.RoleId == "1")
    {
        isMod = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `User.IsInRole(...)` in your view code

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just print them out to preview possible values?

Your code seems to have minor bug to me. I believe it should be

```
@if(Model.Roles.Contains(DON'T_KNOW_WHAT_TO_WRITE_HERE){}
```

(just one '@')

EDIT:
Since Model.Roles are just plain Many-To-Many references, you need to call UserManager to obtain user roles. For example:

```
public class UserDetailsModel {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

and Details action in controller:

```
    public ActionResult Details(string id) {
        var model = new UserDetailsModel
        {
            Id = id,
            User = UserManager.FindById(id),
            Roles = UserManager.GetRoles(id)

        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

You can get UserManager from OwinContext or inject it in controller:

```
    private readonly ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public UsersController(){}
    public UsersController(ApplicationUserManager userManager) {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager {
        get {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Contains uses equals method and it needs an instance of Role to give answer, do you know what object should I pass?

Comment: If you need to check if user is in role, use `UserManager.IsInRole(id,"Admin")`